# Make jQuery ajax calls in order

Tags: ajax, jquery

I want to make a stack of Ajax calls in this way: call(n) starts after call(n-1) finished...

I cannot use **async:false** for many reasons:

- some requests maybe *jsonp* (the most relevant)
- I have other ajax requests that may work meanwhile..
- The browser got blocked

I cannot chain my requests this way:

```
$.post('server.php', {param:'param1'}, function(data){
        //process data
    $.post('server.php', {param:'param2'}, function(data){
        //process data
    });
});
```

Because the number and params of the requests are dynamically created from user input.

A small [example](http://jsfiddle.net/u5HJm/) that illustrates my problem.

You will see that the server response order is random, what I want to achieve is to have it in order

```
Response to arg1
Response to arg2
Response to arg3
Response to arg4
Response to arg5
Response to arg6
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, jQuery [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) returns a [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), this can help you achieve this.

Here is how to do it:

```
var args = ['arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4','arg5','arg6'];

deferredPost(0, 5);

function deferredPost(index, max){    
    var delay = Math.random()*3;
    if (index<max){
        return $.post('/echo/html/', {html:('Response to '+args[index]), delay:delay}, 
        function(data){
            $('#response').append(data+'<br>');
        }).then(function(){
            deferredPost(index+1, max);
        });
    } else {
        return $.post('/echo/html/', {html:('Response to '+args[index]), delay:delay}, 
        function(data){
            $('#response').append(data+'<br>');
        });
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YCXhL/1/)

Here I used [**then**](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) function.

I also recommend to read a little bit more about deferred objects, they can solve a couple of common problems.

Comment: You are not utilizing the deferred feature here in any way though

Comment: by using, I mean utilizing: you would be just as well off by placing that in the success callback.

Comment: What is the advantage to using `then` versus adding the function call to the bottom of the success callback?  (Maybe there isn't one in this case; I'm just curious.)

Comment: Also, I think you could save some duplicate code if you put a `if(index == max) return;` case in your `then` handler, instead of writing out a second call to`post`, couldn't you?

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for a queue.

```
var queue = ['arg1','arg2','arg3','arg4','arg5','arg6'];

function runQueueInOrder() {
    if (queue.length === 0) { return; }
    var arg = queue.pop();
    var delay = Math.random()*3;
    $.post('/echo/html/', {html:('Response to '+ arg), delay:delay}, 
        function(data){
            $('#response').append(data+'<br>');        
    }).then(function() {
        runQueueInOrder();
    });        
}

runQueueInOrder();
```

You don't need to use jQuery's `then` for this to work if you've encapsulated the processing of the queue in a function. It's handy though. The code is destructive as it removes elements from the original array (but as they are processed, it's usually OK).

The method `runQueueInOrder` is called to initiate processing.

When there is no more work to be done, the function simply exits. (I've written a version that polls on a timer before, but that's not needed here).

The function grabs the next work `arg`, calls your `post` call syntax, and when done uses jQuery's deferred then callback to call the function again (to process the queue further if needed).

(I looked at the other answer and found it confusing to follow, so I took a simpler approach. Using my simple version, you can add new items as new work is discovered--or remove them.).